# Call Erlang from Ruby

Tags: ruby, erlang

What is the most awesome gem I should use to call Erlang functions from Ruby app? I wish to use rspec for testing some gen_server stuff.

Erlectricity looking solid, but there is no something like Node#rpc, just message passing. Any ideas?

Comment: If you have message passing, you can "mimic" rpc by maintain a server process in Erlang which will listen for your messages and spawn workers to execute them. (rpc in erlang is implemented similarly)

Comment: Maybe I'm stupid but do you mean "start a erl node, expose some function in a module and send the result back to ruby" when you say "call erlang functions" ? Or do you mean "I have a running erl node that expose some functions from a module via tcp/ip or a stdin/stdout"

Comment: "What is the ost awesome gem I should use"...lol. I'm going to get voted down for this, but is this how all Ruby devs talk?

Answer (score 4):

Well. I am using BERT-RPC and happy with it.

http://github.com/mojombo/bertrpc

Answer (score 1):

For rpc calls, [rinterface](http://github.com/davebryson/rinterface) might be the right option. 
From the README:

```
r = Erlang::Node.rpc("math","math_server","add",[10,20])
if r[0] == :badrpc
   puts "Got and Error. Reason #{r[1]}"
else
   puts "Success: #{r[1]}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think (someone prove me wrong) that you shouldn't use rspec for a gen_server at all.
Instead you could, depening on what your gen_server actually does, use eunit.
http://salientblue.com/codenotes/?name=erl_start
and no, its a long way from rspec.